# Comparison between Timers in WinForm Applications

Tags: c#, timer

OK, now i am talking about a timer with accuracy of microseconds (exaggerating) but yes i need to set it to like `100 MS` and obtain something like `99 MS, 101 MS`

definitely, the control Timer is not the best choice :) i tried the system `timer Environement.TickCount` and built a timer upon it, it seems to be quite precise, i just need a confirmation/decline of some experimented person. if you know some other means to get a precise/easy handled timer i really appreciate you sharing the knowledge.

thanks

Comment: May be you should tell what you're trying to do. That would help to answer easily

Comment: i told what i want to do! i said i want to use a timer with a nice accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For timers, I would use the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, though it doesn't come with timestamps. For that, I'd use the standard [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).Now.

Comment: does it differ from TickCount (number of milliseconds since windows started)

Comment: Yes, the TickCount may not be as precise since it [may be up to 16ms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408.aspx) out. Further, isn't it nicer to write `Stopwatch stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();`
// Stuff // `Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("It took {0} milliseconds", stopWatch.EllapsedMilliseconds)));`

Comment: your comment is convincing @Kjhf :) i tried it and it seems to be really better than 'TickCount'